How can I connect a 1-phase, 220-volt motor to a timer and relay switch to alternate between two power sources at set times?
The Motor is a 2-Pole 20A Well Pump that is feeding 2 Properties. This is a residential 120/240V project. The Goal of this is to set up so that we can make it so that each house pays for half of the month water bill.
The question is what electronics are needed to make a control board for this and any way to improve this idea.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

how is this easier or as failsafe than giving your neighbour the money for half the electric bill? Adding an electricity meter in line would not be introducing moving parts that can fail. In fact, chances are, you can even install one without cutting any cables, as a clamp-on meter to the power supply line.

(for a 20A pump, I'd expect the power factor to be printed on the type label, so depending on whether you've got a private electricity contract where you pay for true power only, or an industrial contract where you pay extra for reactive power drawn, that would matter a bit; either way, it's easier to transfer money than to do electrical installation, and it's much harder to get electrocuted when doing a wire transfer, too!)

Are you looking for how to design the circuit yourself, or how to select the characteristics of an available off-the-shelf device?

First intuition: Why two relays? (Most) relays you can buy can switch between two leads, not just "off" and "on", and that's very desirable, because no matter how badly you mess up control, you could not inadvertedly connect the two inputs at the same time.
The next thing is: The obvious improvement to this circuit is to not build it, but instead of doing the hard thing, transferring electric power at a significant amperage through a moving switch, you should do the easy thing and transfer money. Money can be losslessly transported, electric power can't, and money transfers don't electrocute people or damage pumps if done less than perfectly. Fewer sources of errors, no moving parts, fewer parts in total, no need to add new cables. No need for coming up with a control mechanism.
Question then becomes how much money you need to exchange. So, you need an energy meter. Assuming your 20 A pump is probably one of the bigger consumers of electrical energy on your premises, that feels like a "should-have" anyways.
A simple rail-mounted one (which might simply fit in your installation cabinet, where the pump is hooked up, anyways) like this might totally do.

If you don't want to walk down to the meter once a year to read the value displayed, you can also program a microcontroller to count the output pulses this device gives (it gives 1 pulse every Wh), or buy one for a little more money that has a serial port that you can read with e.g. a microcontroller that sends your a LoRA packet or something similar.

"Money can be losslessly transported, ..." My bank statements indicate that the transfer efficiency < 100%. d:^)

yeah, the whole system with money seems to be that there's somewhere losses that are hard to explain to me; according to my calculations, I should be a multimillionaire, but my bank statements indicate a signficant tan

To the asker of the question: judging from the voltages involved in your question, you're probably in the US? I don't know about subsidies in the US; but in Germany, there's low-cost to zero-interest (and that means: free money, considering inflation) loans for building solar power into residential and commercial grids, and that would also cover energy meters. Might be quite relevant if you have a well pump, because the places I've seen these (almond and peach country in California), there'd be large areas to install them (over the very water channels the pump feeds), so that might effect-

ively make operating your pump a lot cheaper – quite quickly; I think the current "average time to pay for itself" in solar panels + inverter installations is in the order of 4 years in California.
